# Plot 2 different data sources for same entity in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

New to Plotly.

I have two arrays. One contains the values generated from a function and the other is existing values from an input data. They both are tracking the price of an entity.

How do I plot this on Plotly? I tried:

```
trace = go.Scatter(
        x = ModelData,
        y = InputData,
        mode = 'markers',
        name = 'markers'
    )
data = [trace]
plotly.offline.plot(data)
```

However, I realised that this wont work as I'm not tracking X-axis vs Y-Axis. How do I do this?

Comment: what about joining the two arrays before plotting them?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, Not sure how I would be able to differentiate between the two datasets then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the measured and modeled data to two different traces and then plot them together.

[image]

```
import plotly
import random

def my_function(i):
    return i * 1.1

InputData = [i for i in range(20)]
ModelData = [my_function(i) for i in range(20)]

MeasuredData = [i + random.random() for i in range(20)]

trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x = InputData,
        y = ModelData,
        mode = 'markers',
        name = 'model'
    )
trace1 = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
        x = InputData,
        y = MeasuredData,
        mode = 'markers',
        name = 'measured'
    )
data = [trace, trace1]

plotly.offline.plot(data)
```